# $SO(3)$ with minimal and maximal trace.

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

Let $O(3)$ be the set of $3 \times 3$ orthogonal matrices. Let $SO(3)$ be a subset of $O(3)$ such that det($A$)=1 for all $A \in SO(3)$. Show that there is a matrix with minimal trace in $SO(3)$ and show that there is a matrix with maximal trace in $SO(3)$.

I know the identity in $SO(3)$ has the maximal trace. I am not quite too sure which one has the minimal trace.

Comment: Is $SO(3)$ compact in $M_3(\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}^9$ by any chance?

Comment: Yes it is compact. I proved that in a previous problem.

Comment: And does the trace define a continuous function on $M_n(\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}^9$?

Comment: It should, because the trace formula can be written as a poloynomial of the coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^9$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trace function $\mathbb{R}^{3\times3} \to \mathbb{R},\ A\mapsto \text{trace}(A)$ is a polynomial function and therefore continuous, and since $SO(3)$ is a compact subset of $O(3)$, there exist $A_1,A_2 \in SO(3)$ such that
$$
\text{trace}(A_1)=\min_{A\in SO(3)}\text{trace}(A),\quad
\text{trace}(A_2)=\max_{A\in SO(3)}\text{trace}(A).
$$

Comment: Is the reason why there is a max. and a min. because the function is polynomial and continuous and therefore using basic calculus you can find a minimum and maximum value of the function.

Comment: Every continuous function on compact set has a minimum and a maximum, and polynomials are continuous...

Answer (score 5):

Let $A\in SO(3)$. Since

- nonreal eigenvalues of $A$ (if any) must occur in conjugate pairs,
- all eigenvalues of $A$ must have unit moduli, and
- $\det(A)=1$,

it follows that the eigenvalues of $A$ are $1$ and $\cos\theta\pm i\sin\theta$ for some real number $\theta$. Therefore $\operatorname{tr}(A)=1+2\cos\theta$, which attains global minimum when $\cos\theta=-1$, i.e. when $A$ is similar to $\operatorname{diag}(1,-1,-1)$.